# Is area under logarithmic curve identical regardless of "dosing" as pharmacokinetics claims?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, area, curves

In pharmacokinetics, it is assumed that the area under a curve is the same even if a substance is dosed gradually. This applies when "first order kinetics" is used. Is this mathematically true?

I graphed two examples, and used a simple app to estimate the area under the curve, and it is close to identical. But would be good to get a mathematical point of view.

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: The area under the curve is simply to total amount of drug.  So of course it doesn't matter how it is dosed... all at once or spread out over years.  How could they possibly be different???  It is like adding pennies to a jar... all at once or one at a time... same total number of pennies.

Comment: What I was thinking is mathematically. Do the result of the functions like those in the examples equal one another exactly?

Comment: The rule is clearly broken for 0-order kinetics (constant amount cleared, not percentage. ) Two jars. Add 10 pennies to one, 2 once every hour to other up to 10. Jars lose 1 every hour. After 4 hours, both will have same amount, 6. After 10 hours, both will be empty. If you graph that, the area under the curve is not the same. Interested in if it holds mathematically for 1-st order kinetics.

Comment: It'd be helpful to include the equations used to model the process. Presumably it's along the lines of $y'(t)=-\lambda y(t)+F(t)$ where $y(t)$ is the amount of substance remaining, $\lambda$ is the rate constant (characterizing how fast the substance is absorbed) and $F(t)$ is an external time-dependent source of the substance.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I feel like I am missing something here.  In the case of a single does, the curve is $\mathrm{e}^{-kt}$, where $k$ is a decay constant. The area under the curve is then $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-kt} \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{k}.$$  To me, this appears to be a constant multiple of the does (with that constant being related to the biological half-life of the drug).  Obviously, this is not my area of expertise, so I expect that I am missing something here.  What am I missing?

Comment: It would also help to indicate what curve you're talking about. At a first reading I assumed it was the amount of substance in the system, but if we're talking about area under said curve then that interpretation isn't sensible. Is it instead the absorption rate?

Comment: @Semiclassical It's the concentration in the blood, that (once equilibrium reached after absorbing) is assumed to be fixed in proportion to rest of body, with a parameter "V" that defines that ratio. I think the area under curve thing might be an "estimate" and not mathematically true, I did some very rough estimates as you see and they were close, so thought I'd ask if anyone has a better understanding of the math.

Comment: @Semiclassical The curve is just quantity halving at set intervals (elimination proportional to how much in body, as enzyme capacity not used up, contrasts to when enzyme capacity is used up as often exemplified with booze), the different curves "dose" all quantity at once, or, a bit at a time. Simplified to that, it should still hold mathematically if it the "theorem" pharmacology uses is actually mathematically true (otherwise it is an approximation, and it seems pretty good in my example drawings, I'm just interested in which is the case. )

Comment: Simplest case I guess is areaUnderCurve(y = dose/2^x) == 2*areaUnderCurve(y = (dose/2)/2^x)?

Comment: computing that with an app online, 1023 D / 1024 log(2) = 2*1023 D / 2048 log(2) is true. Don't understand the math entirely, but, proves that. If doses overlap, seems possible it is also true. if anyone wants to show that to me mathematically, would not mind.

Comment: attempt at overlapping doses, seems to not add up mathematically, 

integral(0=>3) y = D/2/2^x 

+ 

integral(0=>7) y = ((D/2)+(D/2/2^3))/2^x

!= integral(0=>10) y = D/2^x

Comment: To establish a common language, the notes at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK12815/ seem helpful. Then @XanderHenderson's point is the area under curve (AUC) in the simplest case is $$\text{AUC} = \frac{\text{dose quantity}}{\text{clearance}}=\frac{C_0}{K}$$
where $C_0$ is the initial dose concentration and $K$ is the elimination constant. So the language of "AUC is the amount of drug delivered" is misleading. (The units also back this up: AUC has units of concentration * time.)

Comment: Yes I agree. But the concentration is proportional to dose. Or, generally assumed in pharmacology. As long as dose stays in boundaries for "1st order kinetics" (half life elimination. ) So mathematically I assumed the simplest example is any AUC (of anything, regardless of units or context) that halves at set intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the governing equation for first-order kinetics to be

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=-KN+\frac{dN_{in}}{dt} \tag{1}$$

where $N(t)$ is the amount of drug in the system at time $t$, $K$ is the elimination constant, and $N_{in}(t)$ is the amount of drug infused up to time $t$. I'll assume $N(0)=N_{in}(0)=0$ (no drug is present or has been infused by time $t=0$) and that that $N_{in}(t)=0$ for $t\geq T$ (the drug infusion has ceased by time $T$). As such, for $t\geq T$ we have $$\frac{dN}{dt}=-KN$$ and therefore $N(t)=Ae^{-kt}$ which vanishes as $t\to\infty$.

With these assumptions, suppose we rearrange eq. $(1)$ as $$N(t)=\frac{1}{K}\frac{dN_{in}}{dt}-\frac{1}{K}\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{1}{K}\frac{d}{dt}(N_{in}-N).$$ Then the area under the $N(t)$ curve is obtained by integrating from $0$ to $\infty$, and the fundamental theorem of calculus yields

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty N(t)\,dt
&=\frac{1}{K}\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}(N-N_{in})\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{K}[N_{in}-N]_0^\infty \\
&= \frac{1}{K}N_{in}(\infty).
\end{align}
Note that this only depends on the final value of $N_{in}(t)$ and not the infusion schedule.

Comment: It will take me some time to go through your answer. In the mean time, is it basically "yes"? Is there any even more simplified example, as dumbed down as possible, that shows same proof?